# primary key on update-able view in MySQL

Tags: mysql, updatable-views

Is it possible to create primary key on update-able view in the MySQL. If so how we can create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below link might help you...

[MySQL Views in Navicat - How to define 'primary key'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884167/mysql-views-in-navicat-how-to-define-primary-key)

Good Luck!!!

Let me know incase of any further queries...